# Pyspark UDF function returns ModuleNotFoundError due to scope issue

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, user-defined-functions

I have a question regarding the scope of UDF functions in PySpark.
In the example below you can find three different places to define a function that must be used as a UDF:

1. inside the `run` method (where the actual UDF is defined and executed)
2. inside the class that holds the `run` method but outside of the `run` method itself
3. outside the class

Now my question: only situation 1 works. The other two situations raise a `ModuleNotFoundError` of the module that contains the code. I assume that this behavior is due to the fact that i call the functions inside a lambda but I do this so that I can pass another argument (a string) that must be used in the implementation of the function.

What causes this behavior and how can I make situation 3 work?

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

def function_outside_class(value, condition_string):
  # do something with condition_string
  return value

Class Test():
  
  @staticmethod
  def function_inside_class(value, condition_string):
    # do something with condition_string
    return value

  def run(self, df):
    def function_inside_run(value, condition_string):
      # do something with condition_string
      return value

    # works fine
    df = df.withColumn('values', F.udf(lambda value: function_inside_run(value, 'some_string'))(col('values')))

    # returns ModuleNotFoundError 
    df = df.withColumn('values', F.udf(lambda value: Test.function_inside_class(value, 'some_string'))(col('values')))

    # returns ModuleNotFoundError 
    df = df.withColumn('values', F.udf(lambda value: my_function_outside_class(value, 'some_string'))(col('values')))
    
    return df
```